# Dml statements in SP runs parallely or sequencially sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

The stored procedure contains 2 dml statements,ie 2 update queries.
There is a need of executing the 2nd statement only after the complete exection of first query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_pn
AS
BEGIN

Update [db1].dbo.[table1]
SET
    [date1] = DateDiff(MI,[Ar_DateTime],[Departure_DateTime])



    Update [db1].dbo.[table1]
SET
    [InMinutes] = [date1]+some_calculation



END
GO
```

here i want to ensure the 2nd update has to run only after the first update completed
So can i write the stored procedure as shown above or is there any modification required??#
Please sugest

I just want to know the execution details:that is there are more than one dml statements in an sp then are these 2 going to run parallely or run one after another..

It might be a basic question but just want to know some thoughts...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements always run sequentially.

Individual statements can be parallelised but SQL Server will never run different statements in the same batch in parallel.

A great [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu) article discussing this (and more) is [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/)

> This should settle the often asked question whether statements in a
>   SQL batch (=> request => task => worker) can execute in parallel: no,
>   as they are executed on a single thread (=> worker) then each
>   statement must complete before the next one starts.

For the specific example in your question though (perhaps this is an over simplified example?) I would use a single statement

```
UPDATE [db1].dbo.[table1]
SET    [date1] = DateDiff(MI, [Ar_DateTime], [Departure_DateTime]),
       [InMinutes] = DateDiff(MI, [Ar_DateTime], [Departure_DateTime]) + some_calculation
```